# useEffect is called on html change

Tags: reactjs

I'm learning react, and i created simple component which display people and count like this:

```
const getPeople = async (pageNumber) => {
  return await axios.get("https://randomuser.me/api", 
   { params: {page: pageNumber, results: 8 }})
  .then((res) => {
    console.log(res.data.results);
    return res.data;
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    throw new Error("Smth went wrong...");
  });
};

const People = () => {
  const [pageNumber, setPageNumber] = useState(1);
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);
  const [people, setPeople] = useState([]);

  const clickHandler = () => {
    setPageNumber((prev) => (prev = prev + 1));
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    async function Get() {
      try {
        const { results } = await getPeople(pageNumber);
        setPeople((prevState) => [...prevState, ...results]);
      } catch (err) {
        setError(err.message);
      }
    }

    Get();
  }, [pageNumber]);

  return (
    <div>
      {error && <h3>{error}</h3>}
      <h2>{people.length}</h2>
      <div className="person-grid">
        {people.map(({ name, picture }) => (
          <div className="person-card">
            <img src={picture.large} alt={name.first} />
            <p>{name.first + " " + name.last}</p>
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>

      <div className="button-wrapperr">
        <button className="load-button" onClick={clickHandler}>
          Load more.
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

And the result of component is:

[image]

On button click new data is fetched and added to array and all that work ok. But when component is mounted like first time and i have 8 items in array after i change something in html like className, this useEffect is being called but my dependency isnt changed. So array also update and i have 16 items in array.

So my question is how to prevent this useEffect to be called on html change, i want it to just be called when pageNumber changes not when i change className of some element.
I need logic to call useEffect only when pageNumber change, not when html change.

Note: This is because hot reload, this works normaly when i refresh page after changes, i need to prevent it when i change something, i dont want to refresh page and lose state evry time i change className...

Codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/currying-framework-9ok0e?file=/src/People.js

Comment: Are you referring to the local development server and hotreloading when you save your code in an IDE and the app rebuilds?

Comment: yes ofc, this isnt problem when i load app without changing anything.

Comment: So basically this is only a dev issue? You *could* move the fetch logic to the click handler so it's only called when the button's actually clicked instead of being coupled to a component lifecycle. Or you could manually reload the page after a rebuild.

Comment: Is it because of hot reloading? I guess if you reload a webpage after edit your code, then your issue might be gone.

Comment: yeah i know, but i need to have some data on page load first time. Even if i have useEffect with empty dependency[], it will be called on html change twice ...

Comment: @chin8628 exactly, if i reload its gone. But i need to prevent this without reload, i dont want to reload page on every change and be aware of this.

Comment: You can't do an initial fetch when the page mounts ***and*** call the same fetching logic from a click handler?

Comment: @DrewReese yes i can, but even with that useEffect will be called twice on html change, even if it have empty []. I need logic to prevent useEffect to call on evry html change.

Comment: I don't know where your `getPeople` is but it seems that this behaviour is due to the fact that you are spreading your current results with the new ones. If your `getPeople` is outside of the component, this probably means that you're refreshing the component (but not the state), not doing a new request and you end up with 2 times the same results.

Comment: @ItzaMi Yes its outside component, its basicly async function witch return API result. Nothing special about that function.

Comment: @Notch, could you provide a reproducible example? You could paste your code on something like `codesandbox` so that we can see what you're experiencing

Comment: @ItzaMi i added it to post check updates. But this problem is in hot reload, just to know that.

Comment: @Notch, hopefully my answer helps you solve your issue! My `codesandbox` is working as intended, I believe 

Answer (score 1):

I redid your call and worked with it a bit differently.
Now it should work as expected: https://codesandbox.io/s/silly-glade-1duit?file=/src/People.js

The biggest difference here is the existence of `async` since it doesn't feel that necessary. Instead, we're doing a basic API call and we deal with the `.then()` and `.catch()` (notice that I didn't do the `.catch()`) right when we call the function.

Here's your new `getPeople`

```js
const getPeopleNew = (pageNumber) => {
  return axios
    .get("https://randomuser.me/api", {
      params: { page: pageNumber, results: 8 }
    })
    .then((response) => {
      const { data } = response;

      return data;
    });
};
```

After cleaning the `API call` I did the same with the `useEffect` and the `click` event.
We don't really need to have an `useEffect` to deal with the requests for when the page changes if we already have a function to deal with that.

Here's your new `clickHandler` and your starter `useEffect`

```js
const clickHandler = () => {
  setPageNumber((prev) => (prev = prev + 1));
  getPeopleNew(pageNumber).then((response) => {
    setPeople((prevState) => [...prevState, ...response.results]);
  });
};

useEffect(() => {
  getPeopleNew(1).then((response) => {
    setPeople(response.results);
  });
}, []);
```

And your entire new component

```js
import axios from "axios";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import "./People.scss";

const getPeopleNew = (pageNumber) => {
  return axios
    .get("https://randomuser.me/api", {
      params: { page: pageNumber, results: 8 }
    })
    .then((response) => {
      const { data } = response;

      return data;
    });
};

const People = () => {
  const [pageNumber, setPageNumber] = useState(1);
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);
  const [people, setPeople] = useState([]);

  const clickHandler = () => {
    setPageNumber((prev) => (prev = prev + 1));
    getPeopleNew(pageNumber).then((response) => {
      setPeople((prevState) => [...prevState, ...response.results]);
    });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getPeopleNew(1).then((response) => {
      setPeople(response.results);
    });
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      {error && <h3>{error}</h3>}
      <h2>{people.length}</h2>
      <div className="person-grid">
        {people.map(({ name, picture }) => (
          <div className="person-card">
            <img src={picture.large} alt={name.first} />
            <p>{name.first + " " + name.last}</p>
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>

      <div className="button-wrapperr">
        <button className="load-button" onClick={clickHandler}>
          Load more.
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default People;
```

Comment: Yes, it works in this way, because we are just setting array on component mount. Thanks for solution.

Comment: Please include the relevant code changes in your answer so you've a complete answer with link out to supporting resources. As-is it's a little unclear how this answers/addresses the question. What was redone/reworked?

Comment: Sure, @DrewReese, thank you for the heads-up. I thought that my response was explicit enough but I updated my answer as needed!

Answer (score 0):

To avoid useless rerendering you can use this package : https://github.com/gaearon/react-hot-loader

You can specify option to avoid rerendering on hook update :
https://github.com/gaearon/react-hot-loader#hook-support

You can try to look into FAST_REFRESH env variable also, but I don't know if it works the same way with hooks update.

EDIT: on my config I used react-app-rewired to change the webpack config, after the installation you can just create a file 'config-overrides.js' at the root of your project with this line inside :

```js
const rewireReactHotLoader = require("react-app-rewire-hot-loader");

/* config-overrides.js */
module.exports = function override(config, env) {
  config = rewireReactHotLoader(config, env);

  return config;
};
```

and change your package.json script to this:

```json
"scripts": {
    "build": "react-app-rewired build",
    "start": "react-app-rewired start",
    "test": "react-app-rewired test",
    "eject": "react-app-rewired eject"
  },
```

then add this at the top of your App.jsx component :

```
import { hot } from "react-hot-loader/root";
import { setConfig } from "react-hot-loader";

setConfig({
  reloadHooks: false,
});
...

const App = () => <>blablabla</>

export default process.env.NODE_ENV === "development" ? hot(App) : App; // to avoid babel config, don't forget to set your NODE_END to development
```

it should do the work

Comment: Thank you for this solution, but i will try to find solution for normal hot reload if it's possible, thanks again for your time about this solution.

Comment: try to set FAST_REFRESH=true in a .env file, I think create-react-app improved the current hot reloading process

Answer (score 0):

useEffect is running the first time & then reruns on dependency change. it seems like this is exactly what you want. the issue you are describing happens this way: you change the HTML, so the component lifecycle happens from the beginning, useEffect runs once, then reruns on dependency change. the fact that you see the items that were fetched previously, is because of FAST_REFRESH which is a webpack plugin that new versions of create-react-app uses and it doesn't reload the page after a change in files. I suggest you ignore this issue because it's not gonna be a problem in production. but if it really annoys you, you can just do this when you start your development server:

```
FAST_REFRESH=false npm start
```

or add `FAST_REFRESH=false` to `.env` file

Comment: Thank you for clear explanation. I can refresh page when i change html that isn't problem, but i want to learn properly. So should i be aware of that calling useEffect on html change in production, or it is only in hot reload ?

Comment: It's a fast-refresh thing. in production the changes in the html are happening inside react runtime, so your useEffect is not gonna run again if the component isn't unmounted and the dependencies haven't changed. so you don't need to worry about it.